# How to implement GDAL library on Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, mingw, gdal

I need to make a GUI on Qt Creator using GDAL. I'm having some trouble while trying to implement GDAL on Qt Creator. I learned that I should've used MinGW for that. However, I could not find any documentation or instruction showing how to make implementation. Could you guys help?

Answer (score 0):

I will try to help you and tell you what you have to do))
download library's binary, header file (if not found, have to build from lib source)
place in some local folder.
add in .pro file

```
INCLUDEPATH += .../GDAL/Maked/include
LIB += -L/path_to_lib -lgdal-20
```

run qmake, 
build project, 
move gdal-20.dll ,  libstdc++-6.dll , libiconv-2.dll 
dlls in current working directory
how to work with her?  you can see here

[GDAL Warp API tutorial](https://gdal.org/tutorials/warp_tut.html)

[Raster API tutorial](https://gdal.org/tutorials/raster_api_tut.html)

[Using C++ Classes, Templates, and GDAL](https://gerasimosmichalitsianos.wordpress.com/2018/11/30/431/)

Comment: Could you give me the exact download url for library's binary and header files